# ncclient Filters Causing RPC reply to be empty

Tags: ietf-netconf, netconf, ncclient

I'm trying to use Netconf on Cisco IOS XE Router [This one Here it's Public](https://devnetsandbox.cisco.com/RM/Diagram/Index/7b4d4209-a17c-4bc3-9b38-f15184e53a94?diagramType=Topology) but Whenever I use a filter on my commands of `get_config` , `edit_config` or get I get an error. This is is on Cisco iox XE version 17.3.
The `get_config` command does work if no filter is applied [output shown here](https://pastebin.com/2thC1Rnt).

I have tried this on 16.9.3 on cisco ios xe and the I used the same code and it didn't give me errors. Have I just misunderstood how pyang or xml works?

What I can do Right now is connect to the router and get the config without a filter but When I try a filter I get this error:

> ncclient.operations.rpc.RPCError: {'type': 'protocol', 'tag': 'unknown-element', 'app_tag': None, 'severity': 'error', 'info': 'filter\n\n', 'path': '\n    /rpc/get-config\n  ', 'message': None}

What my code looks like for `get_config`

```
router = manager.connect(
    host="sandbox-iosxe-latest-1.cisco.com",
    port=830,
    username="admin",
    password="C1sco12345",
    hostkey_verify=False
)

filter2 = """
<filter>
    <native xmlns="http://cisco.com/ns/yang/Cisco-IOS-XE-native" />
    
</filter>
"""

netconf = router.get_config(source="running", filter=filter2)
```

For `edit_config` I'm just doing hostname to keep it simple. Here is the code:

```
netconfnewhostname = """
<config>
  <native xmlns="http://cisco.com/ns/yang/Cisco-IOS-XE-native">
     <hostname>DangledwasHere</hostname>
  </native>
</config>
"""

netconf_reply = router.edit_config(netconfnewhostname, target="running")
print(xml.dom.minidom.parseString(netconf_reply.xml).toprettyxml())
```

And Finally for `get` command:

```
netconf_filterinterface = """
<filter>
  <interfaces xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-interfaces"/>
</filter>
"""
netconfinterfaces = router.get(filter=netconf_filterinterface)
```

Comment: When I connect to the public instance you mentioned (using a commercial product), I can issue `<get-config>` with filters just fine (both subtree and XPath variants). If possible, you should make your client verbose (log/output all NETCONF messages in a session) to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you should specify namespace as for `<filter xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">`